# get IFolder from IPath for project root

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project MyTestProject. I want to get IFolder object for root. That is the IPath is /MyTestProject. With this IPath object i need to get IFolder object.

I have a folder under this project resource. For this the IPath is /MyTestProject/resource. With this i get the IFolder using the below code

```
IPath path; //and has value /MyTestProject/resource
final IFolder folder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFolder(path);
```

please suggest any way to do this for  /MyTestProject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Projects do not have `IFolder` objects, instead they use `IProject`.

Both `IFolder` and `IProject` extend the `IContainer` interface so most methods are available in both.

Get the `IProject` for a project with

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("project name");
```

So if you want your code to work with both `IFolder` and `IProject` use the `IContainer` interface.

Comment: For my requirement i need to store the IFolder for later use and this is common code. Is there a way to find if the path does not point to a folder? I tried path.isRoot() -- this returns false for both examples above.

Comment: Use `path.segmentCount()`. A project always has 1 segment, a folder always has more that 1 segment (since it must be in a project).